# Updating values, one control to another

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

History, I am an experienced PL/SQL dev learning to use Apex and struggling with some of the concepts.  Before working with PL/SQL I worked with various platforms including Delphi and VB.

Problem, how to pick up the value set in component from another component.  The object of the exercise is to make the report in an interactive grid change dependant on a value selected in a drop down, the value in the drop down being in the where clause as a bind var.  My original setup for this did not work. After various experiments with this I produced this test case where the object is for the label to display the value selected in the drop down:-

[Page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HFyl.png)

P300_SELECT (left) is a simple drop down, unmodified with the default values.  P300_SELECTED_VALUE is a label set to display the value in P300_SELECT:-

[Component setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhoEd.png)

This does not work!  And it continues not to work when I change the source setup of the label to be STATIC VALUE and set the value to &P300_SELECT.

I have also tried adding a CHANGE dynamic action on the drop down to call refresh on the label, it still does not work!  In desperation to confirm that the value was indeed changing for the drop down I added a second true action to the change event executing the following javascript:

apex.message.alert($v("P300_SELECT"));

Sure enough, this works showing that the event is firing and that the value is correct:-

[Label no change, but alert message works...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtudd.png)

SO WHAT IS HAPPENING?
Why does the label not update even with a refresh called on it?
What do I have to do to make this work?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Bob

Comment: did you call refresh?

Comment: simple example with brief explanation http://wikisend.com/download/869100/f54028_page_3.sql

Answer (score 1):

To do this

1 - Create one dynamic action to start when you change the value of P300_SELECT.

2 - Now there is a lot of ways to do this step, but I will sugest to do in this way. Create one true action in this dynamic action, this true action is "Execute PL/SQL code". The code is:

```
BEGIN

:P300_SELECTED_VALUE := :P300_SELECT;

END
```

In this true action put the item P300_SELECT in the field "Items to submit". And the item P300_SELECTED_VALUE in "Items to Return".

3 - Now create one more true action in this same dynamic action. This true action is "Refresh" and select the region of your report/IG.

---

***If the item P300_SELECTED_VALUE is just to test, so discard the first true action above and fill the field next of your select statement "Page items to submit" with the item P300_SELECT.

---

Why what you have try don't work?

1 - The source section is used to set the value when the page is loaded, this setup not affect changes after the page is loaded.

2 - The report is not refreshed because the item is not in the session after you change it.

---

Ex. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:15

Use this workspace to check something:

```
workspace: STACKQUESTIONS
user: test
password: test
app: 145797
page: 15
```

login on: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550

Comment: HI Thanks Romeul! :-)  - After much experimentation and reference to another item I found here late on Friday afternoon I made this work as you describe, but I was not at all sure it was the correct method!  Is there an article anywhere that describes the Apex event model and how it goes together?  I think some such overview article would help my understanding greatly.  Thanks for taking the trouble to respond... - Bob